# Why audio error is showing up when it is played muted

Tags: javascript, html

I have a error which is

> **Error showing is :**
> Uncaught DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

The error does not prevent function to run but it should not be shown as some of the question in **SO** , **Chrome** , **Mozilla** documentation states that audio or video which are muted are not blocked from playing.

So there must be something I am doing wrong . Can you tell that or any way to remove the error.

I have muted the audio at first hand then why it is still showing up . As function is running every second so error is also showing up every second .

The error stop showing up when I click the `start` btn which plays the audio .

Is there any way to remove this error :

```js
var start = document.getElementById("triggerSnd")
var audioElement = document.getElementById('audiotag1')
var demo = document.getElementById('demo')
var interval, isMuted = true

clockRunner();
clock();
setInterval(() => clock(), 1000)

start.addEventListener('click', clockRunner)

function clockRunner() {
  audioElement.muted = isMuted
  start.innerText = isMuted ? "Start" : "Stop"
  isMuted = !isMuted
}

function clock(isMuted) {
  //Clock code goes here , here only used a simple timer
  demo.innerText = new Date();
  audioElement.play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="audiotag1" src="https://soundbible.com/mp3/Tick-DeepFrozenApps-397275646.mp3" preload="metadata"></audio>
<button id="triggerSnd">Start</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**It is not showing up in above snippet but can seen in console of VS code(Using it, so can tell about it) every second**

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: it is working correctly atleast for me.

Comment: @MuhammadAliDEV Yes audio is playing correctly  and working correctly but error is showing up until btn is clicked. I am using VS code and can see error in debug console

Comment: The error tells you what you need to know. You can’t play an audio file automatically without it user interaction first.

Comment: @Terry But autoplay is allowed in muted form means that muted audio or video can be played automatic